# Easiest way to duplicate rows

Tags: mysql

The closest I can find to what I want to do is [How to duplicate related rows](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46688/how-to-duplicate-related-rows), but my inexperience gets me lost. Basically, I want to copy a number of records, change one column and insert them back into the same table (so its almost a duplicate of the original data).

Table *menuship* is a hash table for a food menu (each row in the table will identify a menu category (starter, main course, or dessert for example), and products (fish and chips).

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `menuship3` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `headhash` char(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `menucardhash` char(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `menucathash` char(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `producthash` char(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `headhash` (`headhash`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=52 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

In programming circles, I would say I want to "fork" my data...

If my table content was like so:

| id | headhash | menucardhash | menucathash | producthash |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | aaa | aaa | aaa |
| 2 | aaa | aaa | aaa | bbb |
| 3 | aaa | aaa | aaa | ccc |
| 4 | aaa | aaa | bbb | ddd |
| 5 | aaa | aaa | ccc | eee |
| 6 | aaa | other | xyz | fgi |
| 7 | aaa | other | xyz | fgh |

I want to duplicate all records with menucardhash aaa (rows 1-5), so I will end up with a table containing 12 records. The extra records will have new menucarhash qqq instead of menucardhash aaa.

| id | headhash | menucardhash | menucathash | producthash |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | aaa | qqq | aaa | aaa |
| 9 | aaa | qqq | aaa | bbb |
| 10 | aaa | qqq | aaa | ccc |
| 11 | aaa | qqq | bbb | ddd |
| 12 | aaa | qqq | ccc | eee |

The result in effect means I have records that have similarity, records 1-5 are similar to records 8-12 - the differences being the id and menucardhash columns.

I was just going to select the records within PHP, change menucathash and send them back to the db, but I wondered if there was an SQL query that could do this for me and thus reduce cpu cycle overhead.

Is this possible via one or two queries, or am I better off having PHP carry the weight?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is a very simple `INSERT .. SELECT` query.

The `id` is not included in the column list as it has the `AUTO_INCREMENT` property and will get values automatically. You only need to replace `'aaa'` with the menucardhash value that you want to duplicate from and `'qqq'`  with the new value:

```
INSERT INTO menuship3
    (headhash, menucardhash, menucathash, producthash)
SELECT 
    headhash, 'qqq', menucathash, producthash
FROM 
    menuship3
WHERE 
    menucardhash = 'aaa' ;
```